# Why invalid number error when working with string functions and string data?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, string-formatting

[Using LPAD requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm), all of my expressions are characters.
Why am I getting an `ORA-01722: invalid number` message?

I want to left pad my varchar2 value with leading zeroes. 
All my airpor_codes are up to three bytes and I want to left pad with leading zeros, if necessary.

In this example, I want  `0777` and `0LAX`.

```
/* This works */ 
with numeric_airport_code 
as (select '777' as airport from dual)
select airport,
       to_char(airport,'0000') as to_char_padding,
       lpad(airport,4,'000')    as lpadding
from numeric_airport_code;


/* This gives invalid number error */

with alpha_airport_code
as (select 'LAX' as airport from dual)
select airport,
        to_char(airport,'000') as to_char_padding,
       lpad(airport,4,'000')    as lpadding
from  alpha_airport_code;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lpad` isn't the problem, it's the `to_char()`. In the second query you're doing:

```
to_char('LAX', '000')
```

which is trying to to an implicit conversion to number first:

```
to_char(to_number('LAX'), '000')
```

... and `to_number('LAX')` of course gets ORA-01722. It doesn't make sense to call `to_char()` for something that is already a string. At best you'll get unnecessary conversions, but often - as here - those are implicit and/or will fail.

If you *only* use `lpad` it does what you said you want:

```
with airport_code as (
  select '777' as airport from dual
  union all select 'LAX' as airport from dual
)
select airport,
       lpad(airport, 4, '0') as lpadding
from airport_code;

AIR LPAD
--- ----
777 0777
LAX 0LAX
```

Also notice that you only need a single zero in the third argument.

Comment: I wasn't aware that to_char converted to number before converting back to char. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @zundarz - there are two versions of `to_char()`; ones takes a number, the other takes a date. If you pass any other data type it has to be implicitly converted to either number or date, or there would be no matching function at all. If you pass a string, that conversion is to a number.